# OS X Yosemite Spotlight extensions

Tags: spotlight, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to extend spotlight's search feature to support additional commands?

For example, is it possible to define custom web search aliases, meaning I could type yt  and it would provide results from youtube.

Alternatively, is it possible to add additional system commands were I could type sl (or some variant) to put my computer to sleep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not possible, there are only [4 types of extensions for OS X Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1):

> Today - Get a quick update or perform a quick task in the Today view of Notification Center
>   Share - Post to a sharing website or share content with others
>   Action - Manipulate or view content within the context of another app
>   Finder - Present information about file sync states directly in Finder.

All of these extension types are explicitly activated by the user for functionality. Apple has said that they are just getting started with extensions and plan to add more in the future, so logically it seems that Spotlight extensions are next (goodbye Alfred :sadface:).

Comment: This is outdated by now, see me answer below.

Answer (score 11):

In the meantime there is Flashlight (The missing plugin system for Spotlight) http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/

This is expandable with Python scripts.

**UPDATE Oct 2016** It seems that Flashlight is not longer maintained. The last update was more then a year ago. Check the repo here: https://github.com/nate-parrott/Flashlight

**UPDATE Mar 2017** There is a fork which is still maintained: github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight – Thanks @amoebe

Comment: This is also outdated. OSX does not allow Flashlight to work after El Capitan update.

Comment: That is also kinda outdated. You can run it again, provided you are willing to turn off system integrity protection for install time (and then turn it on again)

Comment: This is outdated.

Comment: There is a fork which is still maintained: https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight

Answer (score 4):

I have an alternate solution for you which I am currently using. It's native to the OS and does not require disabling System Integrity Protection in order to install Flashlight.

[image]

Using **Automator** to create a new Service. Then with Ask For Text node you can display a popup similar to spotlight. From there the possibility are numerous. For web search there is a command like Display Webpages. The top `activate` AppleScript command is for gaining focus of the following popup.

You can construct the URL from your input text using JavaScript node. You can parse "yt" to YouTube search url for example and put the rest after the space to the URL.

Then in Preference you can set this new service as a shortcut for easier access.

[image]

[image]