# macOS Sierra Spotlight extensions

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, spotlight

Unfortunately I could not find anything up-to-date online about this topic. Similar to the question stated here:
[OS X Yosemite Spotlight extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25130549/4295410), is it possible *by now* to *extend* **Spotlight** on **macOS Sierra**?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Github user w0lfSchild is still actively maintaining this project: https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight, which also allows writing your own plugins.
It is actually a fork of the Flashlight project mentioned in the post you linked to

Comment: …but note that it's got some major unresolved bugs right now, e.g. https://github.com/w0lfschild/Flashlight/issues/17